# Google Colab date is wrong after setting the timezone

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, google-colaboratory

I have been trying to set up google colab to use today's date set from US/Eastern time (I'm on the west coast US, PST which is an added wrinkle) this fails after 7pm ET. I have tried the code below and on 2/19/2021 it returns 2/20/2021 at 7pm PST (10pm ET).

```
!rm /etc/localtime
!ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Eastern /etc/localtime
!date

dateofinterest =  datetime.date.today()
print(dateofinterest)
```

Any thoughts or ideas on how to get my colab instance into a particular timezone?

Comment: In stead of changing the system time you could set the time zone with [`pytz`](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/)